# Can a function determine whether the last call of that function occured synchronously in the event loop?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

Say I have a function `fn` which is called elsewhere under unpredictable circumstances, and I want to be able to distinguish between consecutive synchronous calls of the function, and asynchronous calls of the function. That is, distinguish between:

```
// synchronous
fn();
doSomething();
fn();
```

and

```
// asynchronous
fn();
setTimeout(fn);

// also asynchronous
Promise.resolve()
  .then(fn);
fn();
```

If the next call of `fn` is during a *separate task* (or message), it's relatively easy: the callback passed `Promise.resolve().then` will run as a microtask, just before the current [message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) (macrotask) finishes, so one can check/set a flag when the function is called, and reset it in the microtask.

```js
const fn = (() => {
  let calledDuringThisMessage = false;
  return (arg) => {
    console.log('fn running', arg);
    if (calledDuringThisMessage) {
      console.log('Duplicate synchronous call!');
    }
    calledDuringThisMessage = true;
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        calledDuringThisMessage = false;
      });
  };
})();

fn(1);
fn(2);
setTimeout(fn, 0, 3);
```

This works when the possible-asynchronous calls of `fn` are separated by macrotasks. But if they're separated by a *microtask* like the `.then` of a Promise, is there any way to differentiate between them?

If possible, I would imagine that this would involve listening for an event (or something) that occurs once the stack is empty, or the ability to get a unique identifier from the top function in the current stack, or something like that.

Of course, if I have control over where `fn` is being called, I could change the code *there* to watch for duplicate calls by setting a flag somewhere (in the function at the top of the stack, if need be), but is this possible internally?

Comment: I'm really curious if there's a real world use case for this. Your code should never need to know whether two invocations were part of the same message, unless you're coding some kind of visualizer for the event loop itself. Typically the simple solution is debouncing or throttling the function.

Comment: Put another way, if you have no control over where `fn` is being called, and somebody changes `fn(1); fn(2)` to `fn(1); setTimeout(() => fn(2))`, do you want that to behave differently? If not, there's no real value in figuring out whether the invocations were part of the same message.

Comment: It's mostly theoretical. I ran into the idea when I realized that my complicated outer calls of `fn` from all over the codebase always required something else to happen just before its first synchronous call (maybe call it `prepareFn`). I was thinking of refactoring to call `prepareFn` inside of `fn` when needed, but then realized that microtasks would make that difficult. (yes, I'd want to differentiate between `fn(2)` and `setTimeout(() => fn(2))` if both are preceded by `fn(1)`, because the second is asynchronous, and the first isn't)

Answer (score 0):

im really hoping, this is helping you. You can "register" functions so that they are put in a custom stack when they are called.

```
const MY_FUNCTION_STACK = [];

function register(func) {
    return function (...args) {
        MY_FUNCTION_STACK.push(func);
        return func(...args);
    }
}

function test1() {
    return 1;
}

test1 = register(test1);

test1(); // returns 1
test1(); // returns 1

MY_FUNCTION_STACK; // returns [test1(), test1()]
```

this will not alter the original functions so you can use it to register third party methods. 
You could also add timestamps or whatever additional informations about the functions you want (and sort it later by DateTime).
Also with this solution you can choose if you want to add a function call to the stack

- at the begigining of a Promise
- or the end of a Promise
- or only if the promise gets resolved
- ...

you have the full control.

**EDIT:**

The below example is usuable if you only want certain functions to log. If you want to log all functions you can use the following code:

```
const originalPrototypeCall = Function.prototype.call;

Function.prototype.call = function call(...args) {
    MY_FUNCTION_STACK.push(this);
    return originalPrototypeCall.bind(this)(...args);
}
```

Please remeber that altering system prototypes is no good practise and can cause a lot of unexpactable trouble.